definite integral involving u-sub with parameterized curves
While proving a pretty simple argument about reverse parametrization of a complex-valued function, I have an integral of the form:
$$
\int_a^b f\bigl(\gamma(a+b-t)\bigr)\cdot\bigl(-\gamma'(a+b-t)\bigr) \, dt
$$
(with $\gamma: [a, b] \to \mathbb{C},\; f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$)
When performing $u$-sub on this, I reason as follows:
\begin{align}
u &= a+b-t \\
du &= -dt \\
u(a) &= b \\
u(b) &= a \\
\therefore \quad
\int_a^b f\bigl(\gamma(a+b-t)\bigr) \cdot \bigl(-\gamma'(a+b-t)\bigr) \, dt 
&= -\int_{u(a)}^{u(b)} f\bigl(\gamma(u)\bigr) \gamma'(u)(-1) \, du \\ 
&= \int_b^a f\bigl(\gamma(u)\bigr) \gamma'(u) \, du \\
&= -\int_a^b f\bigl(\gamma(u)\bigr) \gamma'(u) \, du
\end{align}
This is just standard $u$-sub stuff right?
In my textbook they reason slightly more 'directly' that $\gamma'(u) = -\gamma'(a+b-t)$ (in addition to $du = -dt$) and leave the limits of integration as they are, I assume this is just a shortcut / more informal way of making the same argument? Just wanna make sure I understand the process completely.

I don't really understand what the book is arguing, but your way is correct.
